# Calling another class (no view) from a View Controller

Tags: xcode, class, viewcontroller

I am creating an SQL project in XCODE.  I have one view.  My main view controller is loading the database to a table/array.  I want to add another class just to handle the display of the table in a UITableView.  So, I added another class to my classes folder to handle this function as parameters change.  There were no methods in the *.m file when it was added.

My question is, If I create my own methods int he new class to create and populate the table, how should the new class be called form the MainViewController class?  I assume I cannot use 'viewDidLoad' or 'viewDidAppear' because there is no actual view.  Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

For this propose your should use the existing `UITableViewController` pattern.

`UITableViewController` and `UITableView` relies on data from an `UITableViewDataSource`. Your class should implement the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol to feed data into your `UITableView`.

I drew up a simple example in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131580/dynamically-changing-uitableviews-contents/1132267#1132267), where data comes from an static array.

Comment: THanks, Neils.  I have one additional question if I may:  I noticed you used the [makeKeyandVisible].  If there is no NIB associated with the class, do you still use this method to call the class? Doe the "initwithstyle" in the instantiation correspond to the same name in the  class itself?  -Kevin

Comment: The makeKeyAndVisible is only for windows - it marks the window that will receive user interaction. The style parameter is the "look" of the table - you'd use something like UITableViewStyleGrouped which is a table with groups and rounded corners.